# Just would like to confirm is there simple function to close all browser window

Tags: javascript, php

I just search through the web to find a function ( perferably javascript ) which can force to close all the browser window , but I just found the solution is can only use window.close to close the browser that open by window.open , could advise is there other method can do that except window.close function ?

thanks

Comment: No, you can't close the window you haven't opened. Why do you think you should be able to impact other sites ?

Comment: Security prevents you from closing windows that you did not open up. There are hacks around it that may or may not work, search stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm scared to listen if this will ever be answered.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. *You can only close window that you open*.

User may open many other tabs, windows. A client script should not be able to manipulate the windows which are opened by user. Just think, if you open Gmail and Stackoverflow in Google Chrome, would you allow stackoverflow.com to close Gmail window? Thats the security breach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That would be a security breach

Answer (score 0):

As talking about javascript, you cant do that because window object is the parent of all objects. So you cant go out of the scope of window, Hence you cant do that.

But, If you really want to do that you can do that indirectly. You need to write some server code like servlets in java and use System function to terminate the browser process. Now you just send a request to you server to close the browser windows.

Hope it helps.